# pushManager subscribe does not return anything when using new gcm_sender_id

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

so working with pushManager and it was originally was working with an older gcm_sender_id by returning the pushManager subscription endpoint. But when I put a new sender id on the manifest.json file pushManager stopped working and won't return me anything, not even a error. Below is my code

EDIT: so after leaving my devTools on for a bit, the pushManager returned with an error

```
DOMException: Registration failed - push service error
```

Main.js

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {



    var subscribeOptions = {
            userVisibleOnly: true,
          };

      var reg = swReg.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions).then(
      function(pushSubscription) {
        console.log(pushSubscription);

      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);

      }
    );

    console.log(reg);

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
}
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Push Demo",
  "short_name": "Push Demo",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true,
  "gcm_sender_id": "*new_sender_id*"
}
```

Anyone else working with pushManager experienced this problem before?

Comment: Sure it's the GCM thing? I just experienced the same issue, only not after changing any GCM settings but after (I believe) an update of the mobile Samsung Internet Browser (to version 10.2.00.53 on Android 8.0). It still works with mobile Chrome for me.

Comment: this happens to me on regular chrome for me